Confusion about normal force not being normal in circular motion
I was trying to decompose the normal force restricted to circular motion into radial and angular components. However, I noticed that I'm not getting a "perpendicular" normal vector (shouldn't it have just a radial component?). First, I wrote down the relationship between the radial net force and the sum of all radial forces:
$$\sum{\bf F_{\theta}}={\bf N_{\theta}}+{\bf W_{\theta}},$$
$$m{\bf a_{\theta}}={\bf N_{\theta}}+{\bf W_{\theta}}.$$
To find the angular component of the weight I used ${\bf \hat{j}}=\sin\theta{\bf \hat{r}}+\cos\theta{\bf \hat{\theta}}$, so that ${\bf W}=-mg{\bf \hat{j}}=-mg(\sin\theta{\bf \hat{r}}+\cos\theta{\bf \hat{\theta}})$. Now it looks like ${\bf W_{\theta}} = -mg\cos\theta{\bf \hat{\theta}}$. So it seems valid to rewrite the equations from above as:
$$mr\alpha{\bf \hat{\theta}} = N_{\theta}{\bf \hat{\theta}}+(-mg\cos\theta){\bf \hat{\theta}}.$$
So, $$N_{\theta} = mg\cos\theta + mr\alpha.$$
If I assume the angular speed is constant, I can just say $N_{\theta} = mg\cos\theta$. But here is my question. Shouldn't the normal force have a zero angular component (so it is perpendicular to the tangential speed at any point of the circle)? Also, wouldn't the normal force stop being, "normal"? It would be more like the force required to preserve the circular motion. But how does this even make sense?



However, I noticed that I'm not getting a "perpendicular" normal vector (shouldn't it have just a radial component?)

There is a mechanical force between the ball and the ring. That force may point in many different directions. We can always decompose it into a component perpendicular to the ring and a component parallel to the ring.
We call the perpendicular component the “normal” force and the parallel component the “friction” force. So the normal force will always be perpendicular, and if the force between the ring and the ball is not perpendicular then that indicates the presence of friction.

If I assume the angular speed is constant

This assumption is the important assumption. Because you have assumed a constant angular speed the force cannot be purely perpendicular. Consider, for example, when the ring is vertical. There must be a component that counteracts the weight. By the geometry, that component is parallel to the ring. This parallel component is friction.

Also, wouldn't the normal force stop being, "normal"?

The normal force is still normal. You just need to remember the friction force also.

Thanks @Dale, but I still have a question. Why is the parallel component of that force called friction if doesn't point in the opposite direction of theta hat?

@svc friction doesn’t always point in the opposite direction velocity. Consider an accelerating automobile. Friction points in the same direction as the acceleration, and in fact it is the friction that produces the acceleration.
